# Create Custom Bindings in Ember

Tags: ember.js

Not sure if this is the best way to do it. I need to add a delay before changing the bound from value. There're multiple scenarios for this, but a common one is search on text changed. We type something on a text box and we don't want to filter the list straight away. We would like to introduce a delay. There're multiple ways to achieve this, mainly by creating a custom view.

I was thinking of adding a custom binding. This is how it looks:

```
var DelayedBinding = function () {
  var updateBack = function (target) {
    console.log('called')
    this._scheduleSync(target, 'back');
  };

  Ember.Binding.apply(this, arguments);
  this.toDidChange = function(target) {
    Ember.run.debounce(this, updateBack, target, 5000);
  };
};
DelayedBinding.prototype = Ember.Binding.prototype;
```

It works well when setting the binding in code:

`new DelayedBinding('value', '_parentView.context.term').connect(this);`

Even though it works. It seems like Bindings don't follow the same extensibility patterns as other `constructors` do in Ember, so I'm unsure if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: One additional comment, does that work properly?  I'm a little sleepy, but it looks like each time a property changes you would send debounce a new anonymous function which wouldn't be equivalent to the previous anonymous function and would execute twice just 500 ms later.  It's totally possible I'm wrong on this, like I said, I'm sleepy and not willing to test it out now :)

Comment: Good catch. I tried to simplify the code before posting. Updating now.

Answer (score 1):

My only issue I see with this is you are setting up property syncing outside of ember to some degree.  On the flip side you are using ember methods and the scheduler to do it, so it isn't a terrible construct.  Honestly beside your mechanism above, you could do one of the two below (which I'm sure you're aware of) or you could do a PR for ember for a delayedBindingProperty or something like that.

```
App.SomeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  filterValue:'text they type in',

  filterObserver: function(){
     Ember.run.debounce(this, this.launchFilter, 500);
  }.observes('filterValue'),

  launchFilter: function(){
    // do ajax request, or whatever it is you really want to update
  }

});
```

Or use an underlying real filter value

```
App.SomeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  trueFilterValue: null,
  visibleFilterValue:'text they type in',

  filterObserver: function(){
     Ember.run.debounce(this, this.updateFilter, 500);
  }.observes('visibleFilterValue'),

  updateFilter: function(){
    this.set('trueFilterValue',this.get('visibleFilterValue'));
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks that's useful. I did consider that option, however, it didn't really felt like a controller concern, but rather a view/binding concern. This might just be because I'm used to Silverlight/WPF where we have different types of bindings (one-time, one-way, two-way) and we could extend them easily to work like this. I would be happy to submit a PR. However, I think the real value would be on doing this directly on the template (without having to write a custom view just to set the binding). Any ideas on that camp?

Comment: ... meaning in the template I could say `value=term`, but I've not found an easy way to create this ones e.g. `{{delayed-bind-attr value 'term' 500}}` would work outside of helpers only. The same goes for one-way bindings. I've not found an easy way to declare them in the same context as we can declare two way bindings.